# How to print all 8 timestamps of a prefetch file in windows using python?

Tags: python, windows, metadata, prefetch

Guys as a part of my project i wanted to display all 8 timestamps of a prefetch file in my windows laptop. i am using python 3.0 for this work. i have already tried to to do this by opening the .pf file as a regular file but i showed me error.....
and then i tried something like this

```
yourpath = 'C:\Windows\Prefetch'
count=0 
import os
import io
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        s=str(os.path.join(root, name))
        print(s)
        if s.find(".pf"):
            x_file = io.open(s, "r",encoding='utf8')
            for i in x_file:
                print(i)
```

which gives the error

```
C:\Windows\Prefetch\ReadyBoot\rblayout.xin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/siva kumar/PycharmProjects/delete this/3.py", line 11, in     <module>
for i in x_file:
  File "C:\Users\siva kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1258.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 30: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: A prefetch file is not a text file so you should not be opening it as such. Open it in binary mode (`"rb"` as the mode on your `open()` call).

Comment: its working but that is not i wanted i want read metadata and print timestamps